# Inkscape unable to access ImageMagick

Tags: snap, imagemagick, inkscape

Platform details:

1. Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
2. Inkscape 1.0.2 (394de47547, 2021-03-26) (snap image)
3. ImageMagick 8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.2 and 8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-16ubuntu6.8 (two non-snap versions are installed on my system)

I am using Inkscape's Web extension and tried to export the layout, html and css but I get the error "You must install the ImageMagick to get JPG and GIF." But I already have ImageMagick installed. How do I make snap image of Inkscape use non-snap ImageMagick?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to AskUbuntu

Short answer:  You can't.  Install the flatpack or deb version to do your final export, or do the same in a VM.

**tl;dr**

Snaps are interesting to developers as a method of creating an application that can run across a wide variety of platforms, which is great (for them) but new-ish to old fossils like me - so tricks and tips about using snaps are few...

Snaps run in a sandboxed environment, and are not given permissions to access much on your computer by default.  Instead the developers must build into the snap packaging the request or capability for a given snap to interact with other snaps, or the computer system.  Unless they incorporate the requested capability within the body of the snap.

In the case of [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/), the developers of that application have not ported their code to snaps (yet?)

Our interaction with snaps is based on the interface that is exposed to us.  In the case of inkscape, they have not made available a *plug* (snap parlance) to connect to an ImageMagick *slot*, as can be seen in the list of connections available for inkscape:

[image]

So unless they included ImageMagick in the snap, you are out of luck AFAIK.

I would suggest sending a note to the nice people at [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) asking them to include the ImageMagick libraries in their snap.